# CamelCase resgitraiton of eureka app using REST API

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I'm using eureka server,Config server and zuul server,and registering a rest service using Eureka REST API provided at 
[Eureka REST Operations](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations)

eureka url to register : `http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/DemoClient`
with post body as below :

```
{
    "instance": {
        "instanceId":"localhost:DemoClient58181",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "app": "DemoClient",
        "ipAddr": "localhost",
        "vipAddress": "DemoClient",
        "secureVipAddress": "DemoClient",
        "status": "UP",
        "port": {"$": "58181", "@enabled": "true"},
        "healthCheckUrl": "http://localhost:58181/healthcheck",
        "statusPageUrl": "http://localhost:58181/status",
        "homePageUrl": "http://localhost:58181",
        "dataCenterInfo": {
            "@class": "com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo", 
            "name": "MyOwn"
        }
    }
}
```

i can see the app registered as below

```
<application>
        <name>DEMOCLIENT</name>
        <instance>
            <instanceId>localhost:58181</instanceId>
            <hostName>localhost</hostName>
            <app>DEMOCLIENT</app>
            <ipAddr>localhost</ipAddr>
            <status>UP</status>
            <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
            <port enabled="true">58181</port>
            <securePort enabled="false">7002</securePort>
            <countryId>1</countryId>
            <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
                <name>MyOwn</name>
            </dataCenterInfo>
            <leaseInfo>
                <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
                <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
                <registrationTimestamp>1523540991583</registrationTimestamp>
                <lastRenewalTimestamp>1523540991583</lastRenewalTimestamp>
                <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
                <serviceUpTimestamp>1523538580531</serviceUpTimestamp>
            </leaseInfo>
            <metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"/>
            <homePageUrl>http://localhost:58181</homePageUrl>
            <statusPageUrl>http://localhost:58181/status</statusPageUrl>
            <healthCheckUrl>http://localhost:58181/healthcheck</healthCheckUrl>
            <vipAddress>DemoClient</vipAddress>
            <secureVipAddress>DemoClient</secureVipAddress>
            <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
            <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1523540991583</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
            <lastDirtyTimestamp>1523540991075</lastDirtyTimestamp>
            <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
        </instance>
    </application>
```

when request with url `http://localhost:58080/democlient/sayhello` is accessed 
but `http://localhost:58080/DemoClient/sayhello` is not accessed

when i add route configuration in zuul as

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    DemoClient:
     path: /DemoClient/**
     serviceId: DEMOCLIENT
```

then the CameCase route works.
Is there any way, how i can access route registering with CamelCase via REST api and not specifying route configuration in zuul.

Comment: I'm afraid that's an issue with eureka, you loose case sensitivity. Nothing we can do with the automated routes.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, can i post as bug in spring cloud git issues?